# Send Email using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

Currently I have a UITextView field with the CheckBox "Detect Links" checked. The contents of the field will always be an email address.

What I want to do is allow the users to tap the email address and the mail composer open inside of my app.

I have read how you implement sending an email inside of your app using **MFMailComposeViewController** but how do I capture the user touching the email address, in the UITextView,  and send it to my mail composer code instead of the default action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UITextView` does not support intercepting taps on links, you would probably have to subclass `UIApplication` to override its `openURL:` method. I'm not even sure if this will work. If you want to go that route, note that you have to make your `UIApplication` subclass known to the system in the call to `UIApplicationMain()` in main.m and in MainWindow.xib.

Comment: OK, I'm showing my ignorance. I've got my subclass capturing the email being touched.

How do I open the MFMailComposeViewController from my subclass?

[self presentModalViewController ] does not exist when I'm in that subclass.

Comment: One option is to send a custom NSNotification and have your view controller observe it.